# comparison in dates SQL

Tags: sql, date, teradata, difference

i'm working on a data set in which i have to compare the revenue of one day with last week Same day.

for sample i have shared the data :

```
Date    DAY_IN_WEEK_NAME    onnetMins
9/18/2015   FRIDAY  311,980,365.00
9/25/2015   FRIDAY  361,232,362.00
9/21/2015   MONDAY  299,167,025.50
9/28/2015   MONDAY  292,725,603.00
9/19/2015   SATURDAY    310,260,553.00
9/26/2015   SATURDAY    314,627,373.50
```

For SQL writing i have tried the query as below :

```
sel
 (case when day_in_week_name = 'Friday' then  
 (distinct (onnetMins)- distinct (onnetMins)) end) 
 from MYTABLE group by 1
```

however, it is not working.

can anyone try tweaking this sql?

Comment: It is not working - what's the issue you're facing?

Comment: the sql is not correct i guess,

Comment: i need to find difference in onnetMins for 18th Sept and 25th Sept through SQL query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is query that might help you:

```
SELECT
    t1.DAY_IN_WEEK_NAME
    , t2.onnetMins - t1.onnetMins   
FROM
    MYTABLE t1
    INNER JOIN MYTABLE t2
    ON t1.DAY_IN_WEEK_NAME = t2.DAY_IN_WEEK_NAME
WHERE
    t1.date < t2.date
```